# ExecuteReader, Make field variable

Tags: sqldatareader

I want to make the Data Field a variable I wrote the code as follows.  The SQL works but when I try to get the returned value it returns +StrVariable+  if I remove the + then it returns Strvariable literally.

```
Private Function FUNCTStrSN(StrVariable As String, StrSN As String) As String
    Dim sqlConn As SqlConnection
    Dim sqlComm As SqlCommand
    Dim r As SqlDataReader
    Dim sqlstring As String

    sqlstring = "Select " + StrVariable + "  FROM HistorySNUnit WHERE SN='" + StrSN + "'"
    sqlConn = New SqlConnection(DBConnection) : sqlConn.Open() : sqlComm = New SqlCommand(sqlstring, sqlConn) : r = sqlComm.ExecuteReader()
    While r.Read()
        Dim DBSN As String = CStr(r("StrVariable"))
        StrSN = DBSN
    End While : r.Close() : sqlConn.Close()
    FUNCTStrSN = StrSN
End Function
```

How do I retrieve the value correctly?  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try creating the `SQL Command` with parameters

```
Private Function FUNCTStrSN(StrVariable As String, StrSN As String) As String
     Dim sqlConn As SqlConnection
     Dim sqlComm As SqlCommand
     Dim r As SqlDataReader
     Dim sqlstring As String

     sqlstring = "Select @variable FROM HistorySNUnit WHERE SN=@value"
     sqlConn = New SqlConnection(DBConnection) : sqlConn.Open() : sqlComm = New SqlCommand(sqlstring, sqlConn)
     sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@variable", StrVariable)
     sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value", StrSN)
     r = sqlComm.ExecuteReader()
     While r.Read()
         Dim DBSN As String = CStr(r(StrVariable))
         StrSN = DBSN
     End While : r.Close() : sqlConn.Close()
     FUNCTStrSN = StrSN
End Function
```

Comment: Got this error:  IndexOutOfRangeException was unhandled.      An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in System.Data.dll  Additional information: StrVariable

Comment: error occured on "Dim DBSN As string = CStr(r("StrVariable"))

Comment: remove quotes from r("StrVariable")

Comment: Same error except the additional Information now says SNBoard which is the actual field name.  When I look at the SQL string it has replaced the variables with the correct values but it seems either the execution fails to retrieve the record or it does get the correct record but then this CStr(r(StrVariable)) is not capable of working with a variable name.